# Using Java ASTParser can I parse a .war or .jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am following a tutorial to use ASTParser to parse a Java project:

```
http://www.programcreek.com/2011/08/code-to-parse-a-java-project/
```

But what I want is, using ASTPArser to parse a war or a jar file of a Java project. Is it possible? If yes, can you please tell me how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what these technologies are?

An AST is an Abstract Syntax Tree. An AST is generated when a single compilation file is parsed. 
WAR and EAR are archive files, basically fancy ZIPs with some metadata files that tell special applications that read them (e.g. a compliant EJB server) how to handle them.

The Abstract Syntax Tree of an archive makes no sense. That's like the AST of a folder, or document. But the algorithm should be clear.

1. Unpack the archive to a directory
2. For each .java in that directory
3. Open the file, build the AST, do whatever else you want.

Tools like [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) do similar work under the covers to analyze projects. If you're stuck, or feeling brave, you may want to trace through that code to get an understanding of how they do it.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong but .jar and .war files do not even contain .java files in the typical case.

Comment: Why do you ask about the OP's knowledge of these technologies in your answer? That does not add anything. Even if it was relevant, it should be a comment. Questioning a questioner's knowledge does nothing but annoys or undermines the questioner. Anyway, if OP had a solid understanding of what these technologies are, I'm sure this is the last place they would be.